# Partial fraction decomposition on: $\frac{1}{(1-u^2)^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

how does one perform Partial fraction decomposition on: $\large \frac{1}{(1-u^2)^2}$ ?

the square at the denominator makes it a bit non-standard...

Comment: factor $(1-u^2)$ first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{(1-u^2)^2}=\frac{1}{(1-u)^2(1+u)^2}=\frac{A}{1-u}+\frac{B}{(1-u)^2}+\frac{C}{u+1}+\frac{D}{(u+1)^2}$$

Comment: Too many letters... (was corrected)

Comment: you right, I corrected it, thanks,

Comment: Typo in first term

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: $\frac{1}{(1 - u)^2}$ should be $\frac{1}{(1 - u^2)^2}$

Comment: of course, tks :-)